# Is is safe to upgrade SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I have a windows vps with sql2008 express r2 (with tools) installed, one of my clients require full-text search feature. Sql 2008 with advance services has that feature. So my question is, is it possible to upgrade my normal sql2008 express with sql2008 with advanced tools without loosing any databases ?

Regards
Bradley

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 Workgroup up to Enterprise. See the upgrade matrix [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). However, you should **always** make sure you have backups and a recovery strategy when dealing with critical data.

Comment: Thanks, so according to the upgrade matrix it should be safe to upgrade sql express with tools to sql 2008 express advanced services. I just dont want any downtime

Comment: There will be downtime while you are doing the upgrades.  No easy way around that.

Comment: @Grant is correct. I'd rather do it right the first time than feel the pain of rebuilding the environment from the ground up after a failed upgrade.

Comment: Ok i gave it a try and it failed, it said that this instance cannot be upgraded. I dont understand i have sql express 2008 and i want to upgrade to sql 2008 advenaced features. What am i missing ?

Comment: Might be a dumb question do i have to stop the service first before i upgrade ?